# UICollectionVIew, UITableView, or Custom view?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Does anyone know if the list view in Square Wallet app is a UICollectionView or a custom view?  Wondering how they achieved the list view, but when clicking it the view raises and expands to cover the entire screen.

[image: square wallet list view]

Answer (score 2):

Can't say for certain, but I would use a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. When the table cell is clicked I would used Core Animation to animate the view to fill the entire screens.

There are multiple ways you could achieve this affect though.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, and I thought of that. But in Squares version they don't just expand the UITableViewCell, it appears to leave the cell the same size, but lift the cells contents up and out on a different UIView one layer up. Not sure how to do that?